# NX - Error when importing other publishable modules

Tags: github-actions, nx-monorepo

I have a monorepo made with nx with some publishable libraries, some of them have dependencies between them, when I run locally `npx nx affected -t build --with-deps` it works correctly but when I run it in a github action workflow sometimes it fails to resolve the import of the monorepo dependencies, I think the problem comes from not running the build of the libraries that are as dependencies before the library itself that requires them so it fails, I declare the dependencies in the package.json as `peerDependencies`, does anyone know how to solve this problem? I understand that a solution could be to indicate in each project.json the dependencies of the monorepo itself but I don't know the right way to do this, a little help?